# Creating Own Exceptions

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, error-handling

I'd like some advice on building in known errors. Let's say I have a Windows form that needs to set the source path of an image in an object. It must be:

- A valid path
- An image
- A PNG
- 32 x 32 in size
- No transparency

The thing about catching errors is that I'd like the class to handle the errors as much as possible, instead of the Windows form.

So let's say I had:

```
Public Class MyImage
    Public Property SourcePath As String
End Class
```

and

```
Sub TestImage()
    Dim imgPath As New MyImage
    Try
        imgPath.SourcePath = "C:\My Documents\image001.png".
    Catch ex As Exception
 MsgBox(ex)
    End Try
End Sub
```

`SourcePath` should be a string path that points to a valid image file, that is a png, that is 32x32 and has no transparency. If it is not one or more of those, I just want the `ex` to report back what error(s) are there (like "The image is not 32x32" or "The image contains transparency, which is should not. And it also is not 32x32.). How can I create my own Exceptions for the property `SourcePath` above?

On top of this, let's say I had all the same requirements above, but instead of a 32x32 size, I required a 48x48 size for the image on the `SourcePath`. Is there a way to customize for this?

Thx in advance

Comment: @spender: because i'd be happy with a C# answer as well. either vb.net or c#.

Comment: It seems to me that you are largely confusing exceptions with validations.   If an exception is happening, that means a **serious** error has occurred.   To prevent that, you should supply some validations in your UI.

Comment: Exceptions can be used to supply validations :) refer to the WPF and Silverlight Exception based UI validation objects. I would think that throwing a set of different exceptions, each with their own message would be a valid way of processing the file, but this would mask real exceptions like a corrupt file, permissions and File not Found exceptions

Comment: @TerrorAustralis: you could avoid masking real exceptions if you kept all your validation exceptions in the same hierarchy. Say, make them all derive from `ValidationException`, and `catch(ValidationException)`. This way you can even supply better info than simply the `Message` property on `Exception`. Oh, wait, you point that out in your answer...

Comment: @Martinho, This is indeed correct and it is the method i used in my answer (see below). But when simply using the default try/catch like the OP has done, you end up hiding real issues. I should probably have been more explicit in my response :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use something like this:

```
public class InvalidImageException : Exception
{
    public InvalidImageException() { }
    public InvalidImageException(string message)
        : base(message) { }
    public InvalidImageException(string message, Exception innerException)
        : base(message, innerException) { }
    public InvalidImageException(System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info, System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context)
        : base(info, context) { }
    public InvalidImageException(string message, MyImage image)
        : base(message) 
    {
        this.Image = image;
    }
    public MyImage Image { get; set; }
}
```

You should probably not be throwing exceptions while setting the SourcePath property. Possibly either have that logic in the constructor (accept a string, sourcepath into the constructor and throw validations). Either way, the code would look something like this...

```
public class MyImage
{
    public MyImage(string sourcePath)
    {
        this.SourcePath = sourcePath;
        //This is where you could possibly do the tests. some examples of how you would do them are given below
        //You could move these validations into the SourcePath property, it all depends on the usage of the class
        if(this.height != 32)
            throw new InvalidImageException("Height is not valid", this);
        if(this.Width != 32)
            throw new InvalidImageException("Width is not valid",this);
        //etc etc
    }
    public string SourcePath { get; private set; }
}
```

Then your code would look like this...

```
try
{
    imgPath = new MyImage("C:\My Documents\image001.png");
}
catch(InvalidImageException invalidImage)
{
    MsgBox.Show(invalidImage.Message);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    //Handle true failures such as file not found, permission denied, invalid format etc
}
```

Comment: +1 -- but you should implement the four constructors of Exception.

Comment: Ordinarily i would completely agree Billy, but as the four constructors relate to the setting of the message i was not sure if they should be permitted in the derived class. Maybe this should be a fifth constructor?

Comment: Yeah, something like this. A couple of questions: 1) what is the `invalidImage` that you've used in the `Catch`? 2) in the `Sub New(image as MyImage)` you've used above for the `InvalidImageException` what should I be doing to create the exceptions? Just a bunch of if/thens and then building a string of possible errors?

Comment: I don't agree with performing the checks inside the Exception constructor - how do you know that you need to create an exception unless you have already performed those checks?

Comment: Kragen, neither do i, my edited post reflects that. But the OP looked like he was trying to throw exceptions on the setting of a property, which were not in any way related to the property so i went for a basic answer. The current edits take into account more standard coding practices

Answer (score 2):

In the setter for the SourcePath property you want to do your validity checking, and throw exceptions as needed.

You can either throw a built-in exception type and pass a string to it to give a specific error, or you can create your own exception classes derived from `System.Exception`.

Comment: I like the idea of using the setter for validation in my property, unfortunately I can't find a way to kick back a validation error to the WinForm from the class.

Comment: An example would be (in your property setter) `throw new exception("Size is not valid");` That would get sent to the Catch Ex statement and the message would be "Size is not valid"

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways that you might choose to do this, however I'd probably do something along the lines of:

```
void TestImage()
{
    MyImage image = new MyImage();
    try
    {
        image.Load("@C:\My Documents\image001.png");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Where `image.Load()` looks a little bit like:

```
void Load(string path)
{
    if (!File.Exists(path))
    {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("File '" + path + "' does not exist.");
    }
    if (/* image is wrong size */)
    {
        throw new InvalidImageSizeException("File " + path + " is not in the correct size - expected 32x32 pixels");
    }
    // etc...
}
```

Some people would argue that you should have your own custom exception type - you can if you like but I've only bothered when the standard exception types don't really cover the exception circumstance (for example `InvalidImageSizeException`).